# Executing the same partial view multiple times in the same view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to MVC and would like some help.

I have a view (below) which displays the products, next to each other. Till here everything is fine.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <a href="@Url.Action("showProductDetails", "Shared", new { ProductID = item.ProductID }, null)">
        <div class='OutsideDiv'  >
            <table class='DivBorder'>  
                <tr >  
                    <td class='title'>  
                        @item.ProductName    
                    </td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr >  
                    <td class='imageBox'> 
                        <img alt='' src="@item.ImageURL" /> 
                    </td>  
                </tr> 
                <tr>  
                    <td class='title'> 
                       @Html.Action("showAverageRating", "Rating" , new { ProductID = item.ProductID }  ) *************

                    </td>
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td class='desc'>
                        @item.Description  
                    </td>
                </tr>   
                <tr>
                    <td class='price'>
                        € @item.Price 
                    </td>  
                </tr> 
            </table>
        </div> 
        <script type='text/javascript'>   $('.DivBorder').mouseover(function () { $(this).css('border-color', '#0953cb'); $(this).css('background-color', '#eaeaea'); }); $('.DivBorder').mouseout(function () { $(this).css('border-color', '#bdbdbd'); $(this).css('background-color', '#f6f6f6'); });</script> 
    </a>
}
```

In the line marked with '****' above I am calling another view (showAverageRating) which for now is just displaying 5 rating stars with the first 3 starts selected.

```
<input class="star  " name="adv1" type="radio" /> 
<input class="star  " name="adv1" type="radio" />
<input checked="checked" class="star   " name="adv1" type="radio" /> 
<input class="star  " name="adv1" type="radio" /> 
<input class="star  " name="adv1" type="radio" />
```

The problem is that on the second item, when the rating stars view (above partial view) is called again, the stars are displayed next to the stars of the first product, picture below.

[image]

I think I have to use something else rather than `Html.Action`?

EDIT : showAverageRating Code

```
public ActionResult showAverageRating(int ProductID)
{
    decimal averageRating = new RatingsService.RatingsClient().getAverageRating(ProductID);
    ViewData["averageRating"] = averageRating;
    return PartialView();
}
```

Comment: can you post showAverageRating Action code

Comment: public ActionResult showAverageRating(int ProductID)
        {
            decimal averageRating = new RatingsService.RatingsClient().getAverageRating(ProductID);
            ViewData["averageRating"] = averageRating;
            return PartialView();
        }

Comment: check edit of main post, better than above comment

Comment: partial view as well please

Comment: the view is the part with the inputs above in main post

Comment: is this your complete partial view, because your view is fine it should not render stars 2nd time in the first product

Comment: I do have this - @{decimal averageRating = ViewBag.averageRating;} at the top, but I am not using it. I removed it and left the inputs only, still the same output

Comment: your comment the inputs in partial view and then check what happens

Comment: I commented the inputs, they just didnt appear.

Comment: I have just typed a bunch of characters, and they got displayed as they should. The problem is something with the jquery of the rating stars. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the name of the stars where identical, so I included the productID with their name, like below.

showAverageRating partial view

```
@{decimal averageRating = ViewBag.averageRating;}
@{int productID = ViewBag.productID;}

<div id="averageRating"  >
    <input class="star" name="star+@productID" type="radio" /> 
    <input class="star  " name="star+@productID" type="radio" />
    <input checked="checked" class="star   " name="star+@productID" type="radio" /> 
    <input class="star  " name="star+@productID" type="radio" /> 
    <input class="star  " name="star+@productID" type="radio" />  
</div>
```